# How to check if the given value belong to the vectors in list?

Tags: r, list, vector

Suppose we have a value  y=4, and a  list of vectors, I want to check if this value belongs to any vector in the list if yes, I will add this value to all the elements of vectors.

```
 y<-4
 M<- list( c(1,3,4,6) , c(2,3,5), c(1,3,6) ,c(1,4,5,6))

> M
[[1]]
[1] 1 3 4 6

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 5

[[3]]
[1] 1 3 6

[[4]]
[1] 1 4 5 6
```

The  outcomes will be similar to :

```
 > R
  [[1]]
  [1] 5 7 8 10

[[2]]
[1] 5 8 9 10
```

Comment: Then the list elements without 4 are dropped?

Comment: yes, I  want to get only the vectors contain value 4 and add this value to their elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `keep` which only keeps elements that satisfy a predicate. In this case, it is only keeping the vectors that contain `y`.

We then add `y` to each of the vectors.

```
library('tidyverse')

keep(M, ~y %in% .) %>%
  map(~. + y)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple hacky way to do this:

```
lapply(M[sapply(M, function(x){y %in% x})],function(x){x+y})
```

returning:

```
[[1]]
[1]  5  7  8 10

[[2]]
[1]  5  8  9 10
```

**Logic:** use `sapply` to work out which parts of M have a 4 in, then add 4 to those with `lapply`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with...

```
lapply(M[sapply(M, `%in%`, x=y)], `+`, y)

[[1]]
[1]  5  7  8 10

[[2]]
[1]  5  8  9 10
```

Comment: This is a cleaner (perhaps more esoteric) version of michael-bird's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method with `lapply` and set functions.

```
# loop through M, check length of intersect
myList <- lapply(M, function(x) if(length(intersect(y, x)) > 0) x + y else NULL)
# now subset, dropping the NULL elements
myList <- myList[lengths(myList) > 0]
```

this returns

```
myList
[[1]]
[1]  5  7  8 10

[[2]]
[1]  5  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow! everyone has given great answers, just including the use of Map functionality.

```
Map("+",M[unlist(Map("%in%", y,M))],y)

[[1]]
[1]  5  7  8 10

[[2]]
[1]  5  8  9 10
```